# VBA excel Copy Paste

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Hi, I am totally new to Excel VBA. Firstly, I want to copy the data when the condition is met(copy data with reference to 144) 
Secondly, compare the cells, if it is IT Operations(Table1) to IT Operations(Table2) then copy the price(money) to column F. If the variable is no there then leave blank.

Comment: Apart from not understanding what you are doing, your question gives absolutely no indication of what the problem you are facing is.

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code. Take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider.[Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/) or [Mid-Advanced Tutorials](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/codes-examples-macros-how-tos-most-useful-basics-advanced/) and my [personal favorite](http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with formulas. Here is one way of thinking about filling column F, with the prices for the matching items in column E, by matching the number given in the last row in E (`144 Total`); which i shall assume is `E10` in this case.

Total formula in `F1` which you then drag down is:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E1,INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET($H$1,MATCH(1*LEFT($E$10,FIND(" ",TRIM($E$10),1)-1),$G:$G,0)-1,,1,1))&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET($I$1,MATCH($E$10,$G:$G,0)-1,,1,1))),2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(E1,G:I,3,FALSE)),"")
```

In steps:

Extract the number of interest e.g. `144`, and get rid of any trailing/leading whitespace using:

```
LEFT($E$10,FIND(" ",TRIM($E$10),1)-1)
```

Find which row this value is in as this will be the first row of the lookup range for this number.  `*1` converts text to a number.

```
MATCH(1*LEFT($E$10,FIND(" ",TRIM($E$10),1)-1),$G:$G,0)
```

This gives row 9.

We can use something simpler to find the last row of the range, which holds `144 Total`

```
MATCH($E$10,$G:$G,0)
```

This gives row 15. So we know the data lies between rows 9 and 15 for `144`.

We can turn this into a range to use in a `VLOOKUP` with `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET`.

```
=CELL("address",OFFSET($G$1,MATCH(1*LEFT($E$10,FIND(" ",TRIM($E$10),1)-1),$G:$G,0)-1,,1,1))&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET($H$1,MATCH($E$10,$G:$G,0)-1,,1,1))
```

This gives us `$G$9:$H$15`. Note adjustments of `-1`, to put `OFFSET` back in the right row, and that the `OFFSET` start cells are in different columns to provide the columns required for the `VLOOKUP`.

So we can now lookup column E values e.g. `Enhancement`, in our newly defined range which is accessed via `INDIRECT`:

```
=VLOOKUP(E1,INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET($H$1,MATCH(1*LEFT($E$10,FIND(" ",TRIM($E$10),1)-1),$G:$G,0)-1,,1,1))&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET($I$1,MATCH($E$10,$G:$G,0)-1,,1,1))),2,FALSE)
```

This is saying `VLOOKUP(E1,$G$9:$H$15,2,FALSE)` i.e. get the `price` column from the range for the item specified in `E1`.

If this is not found i.e. returns `#N/A`, we can use this to first check if this is because of the merged cell that holds the `144 Total`; where the value is actually in column G not H, and use an `IFERROR` to say, if not found in `$G$9:$H$15` then try for a match using columns `G:I` and return column 3.

Which with pseudo formula, using `priorLookup` as placeholder, for the formula described in the steps above, looks like:

```
 IFERROR(priorLookup, VLOOKUP(E1,G:I,3,FALSE))
```

If this still returns `#N/A`, we know the value is not present and we should return `""`. This we can handle this with another `IFERROR`:

```
 IFERROR(IFERROR(priorLookup, VLOOKUP(E1,G:I,3,FALSE)),"")
```

So giving us the entire formula stated at the start.

Here it is used in the sheet:

[image: Formula in sheet]